# Excel JS addin with WebAPI - need sample or snippet

Tags: office-js

i am looking for some help on following subject -
•   We are trying to create an Office/Excel Add-in which will get data from an WebAPI, update the worksheet and then push data back via WebAPI. 
•   Should be able to support Office Version 2013 using HTML/JavaScript add-in.
•   The add-in may perform cross domain calls to WebAPI. Are there any Authentication or authorization issues?
•   I am really looking for any examples or sample code on this subject

Comment: Describe what you already have done for the topic you raised.

Answer (score 0):

Most Web APIs would require authorization. See the following for an overview of how to do this and links to samples: [Authorize external services in your Office Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins).

Answer (score 0):

For a simple example of using Web APIs, I suggest you look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/06/10/create-a-web-service-for-an-app-for-office-using-the-asp-net-web-api/

For the OAuth example in particular, the [article referenced by Rick Kirkham](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins) is a good one, and I'd also recommend you follow the samples links towards the bottom of the article.  The approach is also used by the more complicated sample add-ins, such as [Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/) (for GitHub gists and profile info).

Comment: Thanks folks for your responses !